# custom endpoints in React-Admin

Tags: reactjs, request, nestjs, endpoint, react-admin

So, basically, I have all kinds of endpoints, and I need to use them on React-Admin.

The thing is, when I pass the endpoint for getting all the products to the DataProvider (nestJS), it adds some queries to the endpoint that I don't want.

Right endpoint:

> http://localhost:3000/products/findAll

Wrong endpoint, that ReactAdmin automatically generates:

> http://localhost:3000/products/findAll&limit=10&page=1&sort%5B0%5D=id%2CASC&offset=0

Here's the code:

```
 const dataProvider = crudProvider("http://localhost:3000", fetchJson);

return (
    <Admin
      i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
      authProvider={authProvider}
    >
      <Resource
        name="product/findAll?storeId=1"
        list={PostList}
        create={AddProduct}
        edit={EditPost}
      />
    </Admin>
  );
```

Comment: please provide your coding implementation to identify the issue

Comment: @KavinduVIndika I edited the post. That's the code, super simple. I'm using a NestJS backend

Comment: React-admin requires that your API handles pagination, sorting, and filtering for lists. How does it expect to receive such parameters if not via the query string?

Answer (score 1):

This is the job of your dataProvider. Are you using https://github.com/rayman1104/ra-data-nestjsx-crud ? You might have to tweak it if it does not generate the correct routes

Comment: Thanks, already solved it! Now I need to use a different endpoint to create an element. Do you know if that's possible? I'm seeing that is Posting to the same endpoint and I'm not able to change it

Comment: Same answer, you might have to tweak the dataProvider